# Oracle: i want to setup some variables for login.sql

Tags: oracle

I use this login.sql for my oracle session

```
select           'You are:          '||upper(user) "Welcome to Oracle on AIX 7.1" from dual
union all select 'Logged into:      '||upper(sys_context('userenv','db_name')) from dual
union all select 'Database Version: '||banner from v$version where rownum <= 2;
```

Instead of using AIX is possible to get some variable?
So when i connect on linux server it doesn't return AIX
I know variable is &variable,but how to set a variable using
sql command "select from..etc"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you absolutely have to have the platform as part of the alias, I would simply pull the platform from v$database:

```
select 'You are:          '||upper(user)  "Welcome" from dual union all
select 'Logged into:      '||upper(sys_context('userenv','db_name')) from dual union all
select 'Database Version: '||banner from v$version where rownum <= 2 union all
select 'On Platform:      '||platform_name from v$database;
```

Comment: You might also want to set the prompt. This will get updated everytime you connect to a new database. set editfile "/tmp/_USER_CONNECT_IDENTIFIER_PRIVILEGE.buf"
set sqlprompt "_USER'@'_CONNECT_IDENTIFIER _PRIVILEGE> "

Comment: @Gandolf989 I considered saying something about prompts, but it seemed to be outside the scope of the question. I use the following myself: SELECT LOWER(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_USER')) || '@' || LOWER(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','DB_UNIQUE_NAME')) as sqlprompt FROM DUAL; set SQLPROMPT '&sqlprompt> '